# How do you prevent copying of satellite assemblies during a build?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, localization

I am using the [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) package, added via NuGet. When I build projects normally, all of Humanizer's satellite assemblies are copied.

We only support a subset of languages and would like to remove their, our, and other third-party satellite assemblies representing languages not supported from the deployment footprint.

We can do that easily enough with a post-build step. I was wondering how you prevent them from being copied in the first place, or if you even can?

My initial searches didn't seem to help. Is there anything in the [CSC command-line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx), a .NET attribute, app.config, or other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262592/omit-localized-versions-of-assemblies-from-the-build-output is a close duplicate of this question.  You might be able to adapt that answer.  Specifically, use that answer to remove all satellite assemblies, but add a new step to copy the specific cultures you want to include in your deployment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omit localized versions of assemblies from the build output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262592/omit-localized-versions-of-assemblies-from-the-build-output)