# How to stop Visual Studio from creating language specific resources dll from resource file names?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, visual-studio-2019

After renaming embedded resource files from insignificant names (**WelcomeA.rtf** and **WelcomeB.rtf**) to contain language codes (**Welcome.en-us.rtf** and **Welcome.de-de.rtf**), the .NET build started splitting my resources off into [AppName].resources.dll files that are located in a language-coded subfolder of the output directory. The **de-de** and **en-us** folders have not been present before and all I did was rename source files, not changing project settings:

```
D:\[AppName]\BIN\DEBUG\NET5.0-WINDOWS
│   [AppName].deps.json
│   [AppName].dll
│   [AppName].exe
│   [AppName].pdb
│   [AppName].runtimeconfig.dev.json
│   [AppName].runtimeconfig.json
│
├───de-de
│       [AppName].resources.dll
│
├───en-us
│       [AppName].resources.dll
│
└───ref
        [AppName].dll
```

My Application does not support whatever I18N pattern Visual Studio is trying to implement here.
I was locating and loading the embedded document into a RichTextBox by doing something like this, which is now broken:

```
private void LoadWelcomeText(string langCode)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();

    foreach (string s in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
    {
        if (s.Contains("Welcome." + langCode + ".rtf"))
        {
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(s);
            richTextBox.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I force the build process to not restructure my application architecture **from source file names**?
(I am aware that renaming the files to not match whatever pattern is used to guess the I18N intent here, but I'd like to fix the problem, not work around it.)

Comment: Those dlls with language-specific resources are called [satellite assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-satellite-assemblies). You can try to search for topics with it in name, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30262592/1997232) is one.

Comment: Thank you, @Sinatr. I am aware of satellite assemblies, but most resources about them (including the one you linked) show you how to jump through hoops to get them to work.
I'd like to avoid having to deal with them. I want to create small run-once app that is supposed to have a little flag in the corner, allowing you to swap resource dictionaries to translate a XAML UI with dynamic resources. And then there is a text document that needs to be swaped in code behind. It's resource file name is also a dynamic resource string. No need to install Assemblies in the GAC, IMHO :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set resource WithCulture in csproj file.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Welcome.en-us.rtf" WithCulture="false" />
```

Comment: Gosh, thank you! After you told me what to look for (WithCulture), I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477616/how-can-i-prevent-embedded-resource-file-culture-being-set-based-on-its-filename) older post with the same issue. How is this property not shown in the "Properties" window in VS 2019? Reflection, anyone? You have to edit the project file in a text editor. I came back to C# after over 10 years and VS still feels like some indie kickstarter project.